# Flask RestFul - obter sub element com reqparse

Tags: python, flask

Estou montando uma API em Flask e a *request* está da seguinte forma:

Request: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/integra`

```
json = {"recev": {"doc":"123456"} }
```

Estou tentando obter o valor da chave `"doc"`, porém sem sucesso:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse 

class Processa(Resource):

    def post(self):

        argumentos = reqparse.RequestParser()
        argumentos.add_argument('recev')

        dados = argumentos.parse_args()
        vdoc = dados{'doc':dados:['doc']}

        return vdoc, 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, retirei o reqparse e refiz o codigo

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

@app.route('/recebe', methods=['POST'])
def recebeReq():
    req = request.get_json()
    for elem in req:
       doc= (req['recev']['doc'])
       print(doc)
```